# Selenium code in python to fill form after a login page

Tags: python, forms, selenium, wait

Hi so I was designing a python script in selenium that will run fill up a form after login request.
I have been able to fill in my login details and then click on "Submit" after which the browser closes itself automatically.
here is the code which I used to login.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.example.com")

wait=ui.WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(page_is_loaded)

USERNAME = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/center/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")
USERNAME.send_keys("alberteinstein")

PASSWORD = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/center/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")
PASSWORD.send_keys("IamHISson")

Login_Button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/center /div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/input")
Login_Button.click()
```

after this piece of code there is a form which needs to be filled.

I can write a code to fill in the form, the problem is how to make selenium wait until the next page loads and also do I need to provide the link of the next page ?

Comment: This will not solve your issue, but can simplify your further operations with `selenium`: do not use absolute `xpath`, use relative instead! For instance, instead of `driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/center /div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/input")` use `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="radar_button"][@type="submit"]')`

Comment: Thanks, but as you correctly pointed out before. It seems my browser version was old. The issue is now resolved. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `WebDriverWait` module to wait until required elements displayed on page after authorization complete:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, ‘id_of_input_field_of_your_form’)))
```

This code will force `webdriver` to wait up to 30 seconds until input field (that you want to fill at first) displayed on page. If element not displayed within 30 sec `TimeoutException` will be raised

Comment: It seems that my browser session is getting automatically closed after clicking the login button. It does not wait for the next page to load and the WebDriverWait() command does nothing to stop the window from crashing. I have not added any driver.quite() or any such things in the end. Do you think it might be a firefox update issue?

Comment: Does it (browser) close if you make it manually? Are you sure that button you use to call `Login_Button` is really button to submit authorization? Provide a `HTML` for this button

Comment: OR 
usually on browser I can get around the login page by loggin in once(and then opening the subsequent sessions in new tab).

Can I do something like that here and open the page directly in new tab. I have the url of the page which I will reach after I log in.

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure that the login button IS in fact the one to submit authorization. I rechecked the xpath which is mentioned in the above code

Comment: Can you give me an example using selenium and python which will be used to solve a similar problem.
1. There is a login page.(like logging on to wikipedia)
2. Fill in a form (search for a query there after loggin in).
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your situation correctly:)  Does browser closes after you pass authorization and new browser window opens or required form just opens in new tab, while authorization window is still opened?

Comment: The browser closes(crashes) after I pass in the authorization. No new window opens up. I mentioned the new tab thing to get around the login problem.
Like we have for any site say facebook, once you log in it dosent ask you for your details again right. (I am not sure but i think its because of the cookies that gets stored). Similarly I wanted to know if we can open up in a new tab , the page which we get after we have logged in. I do have the url of that page.

Comment: do you get any tracebacks (exceptions) after browser crash?

Comment: just another empty browser window opens up and remains open

Comment: can you execute `driver.get('http://www.second_page_url.com')` after `Login_Button.click()`?

Comment: Its like this :
The page I want to open is the second url only.
but everytime I try to do driver.get(second_url)
It redirects me to a login page

*Sorry for not being able to express the problem in brief ,right in the beginning

Comment: So after you successfully logged in one web-site you get access to another, wright?

Comment: Yes, that's right.
Like try logging to this url


https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLl66YvdTLAhXDxI4KHRxFBvQQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fofficialstackoverflow%2F&usg=AFQjCNEUkYnyYfEcAJ-8fAlzj0fHgO4vXQ&sig2=JHZt4gdTVS5z4spwe8o1TA

It will ask you for your facebook credentials before showing you the actual page

Comment: so try to execute `driver.get('http://www.second_url.com')` in same script after `Login_Button.click()` and let me know the result

Comment: It threw out the following error

`File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 368, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine`






I think it did that because we did not wait long enough for the page to load

Comment: I guess it means that `webdriver` quit and no longer available. Maybe some `javascript` code injection could resolve this issue. Can you provide `html` code for login button?

Comment: `<input class="radar_button" type="submit" value="Login">`

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.support import ui

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

import time

google=webdriver.Firefox()
google.get("http://www.google.com")

QUERY=google.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/input[3]")
QUERY.send_keys("cars")
`

Also I tried simple search on google with the above code. Does this work for you?

Comment: does this code also led to closing browser window and opening new clear window?

Comment: Do you have `chromewebdriver` also? and `Chrome` browser installed? Can you use `Chrome` (`Opera`, `InternetExplorer`) instead of `Firefox`? It seems that you have wrong `Firefox` settings

Comment: Ok, I'll try doing that. Thanks btw. Got to go now

Comment: Thanks, but as you correctly pointed out before. It seems my browser version was old. The issue is now resolved. Thanks for your inputs